How can I bring back kafir lime leaves from a dried to a more supple usable state?
Fresh herbs are better. No arguing there. But after several instances of throwing out 4/5 of the batches of kafir lime leaves that I bought fresh because I never get around to them quickly enough, it's time to look for an alternative.

But even for the simplest uses of kafir lime leaves, such as marinating chicken, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to soften them so that they can serve as a marinade.
How can I bring back kafir lime leaves from a dried to a more supple usable state?
Of course the problem may be that there are uses for this nice ingredient that I haven't figured out yet, and so if answer and can comment about ideas to quickly use larger amounts of the fresh herb (freezing them doesn't work; at all), please do.

Freezing them does indeed work.  I do it all the time.

@moscafj How did you avoid freezer burns? I'm not sure how they can "burn" when they're already dried. Thoughts: 1- freeze them in ice tray cubes (filled with water) 2- freeze them with a dessicant.

I freeze when fresh. You could certainly vacuum seal for extended freezing.  I just put in a baggie and get as much air out as possible.  Sometimes a bit of freezer burn, but they are just fine and retain much of their flavor.

@moscafj Thanks. (Sorry, I was confused there for a second. Of course I was freezing the fresh, not the dried, ones.)

This is not a great solution. It's just an alright solution.
Steam the dry leaves on simmering heat. It will take quite a while (30 minute) to become supple enough so that they will not shatter into small pieces in the marinade.
